# Python: Is it good practice to call a function within itself?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Just a beginner question about good practice.

Take this bit of code for example. I want a particular user input, and if they enter something crazy, I obviously want to run the code inside the function again.

```
def get_difficulty():
    chosen_difficulty = str(raw_input("***  Choose difficulty: Easy, Medium or Hard: ").lower())
    if chosen_difficulty == "hard":
        return 10
    elif chosen_difficulty == "medium":
        return 15
    elif chosen_difficulty == "easy":
        return 20       
    else:
        print "***  Did you enter 'Easy', 'Medium' or 'Hard'?"
        print "***  Sorry that was passive aggressive. You obviously didn't..."
        return get_difficulty()
```

Is it ok to make the function handle the else case like this? It seems inelegant; if the person entered something wrong five times the function would be nested 5 times and eventually the right answer would have to cascade down through the return of each function.

It works fine, but is there a better way?

Comment: What you've discovered, (calling a function from itself) is a fundamental concept in programming called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Comment: . . . except that in this case it's being used to emulate a loop, and this isn't a tail-recursive language, so . . .

Comment: @imallett I admit, I just read the title and skimmed the code.  I agree a loop would be a better approach for his specific case.

Comment: Also, you should probably add the line `chosen_difficulty = chosen_difficulty.lower()`  The options you gave the user was "Easy, Medium, etc" but the options in your `if...elif` blocks user the lower case.

Comment: It is being .lower() ed but it's just off screen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case a loop is the correct way to handle repeated input:

```
def get_difficulty():
    while True:
        chosen_difficulty = raw_input("***  Choose difficulty: Easy, Medium or Hard: ").lower()
        try:
            return {"hard": 10, "medium": 15, "easy": 20}[chosen_difficulty]
        except KeyError:
            print "***  Did you enter 'Easy', 'Medium' or 'Hard'?"
            print "***  Sorry that was passive aggressive. You obviously didn't..."
```

Comment: You have a case mismatch between your dict keys and your passive aggressive error text.

Comment: But it's being `.lower()`ed.

Comment: @tripleee - Thanks.  The lower() was just off my screen.

Answer (score 2):

What you discovered is called "recursion" and there is fundamentally nothing wrong about it. It is a strong concept that often leads to elegant formulation of problems. The Fibonacci numbers are an often presented problem that is easily solvable with recursion: We want to generate the number sequence 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, .. so the `n+1` entry is (n-1) + (n). This leads to the following algorithm:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    """Generate the n-th fibonacci number"""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1))
```

Every recursive function can be turned into an iterative one. For the n-th fibonacci sequence there exists a closed form, you can look it up [in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression). As you see there are two "irrational numbers" that can be expressed by sum/division of square root of two. So sometimes problems are "recursive by nature" and recursive solutions can be short, where as a iterative solution might "look ugly"/"be longer".

So recursion is in general a good thing, but in python it is not always a good solution. As you already pointed out, if a user inserts five time a wrong input the function stack will have five function calls. Python has a max recurion depth and if a user would enter consecutively wrong input he could crash the program. In case of user input this is not realy a problem, but in other cases you can run more easily into the maximal recursion depth.

Tail-recursion (which is not implemented in python) is a way to allow for arbitrary recursion depths. Haskell and lisp uses this concept, you can read more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) or [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).

The canonical way to handle input verification in python is a while loop as pointed out by Daniel.